# .NET Maui Issue With Signing On iOS Device

Tags: c#, ios, .net, maui

I have a project I made in .NET Maui that runs flawlessly on Android & iOS Simulators. I've been stuck on a signing issue when deploying to my device. The only errors i've found that are of value are the logs which include a few different error messages:

```
Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local.AppleIDPasswordProvider Error: 0 : There was an error while trying to retrieve the Apple account passwords list
```

```
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient Error: 0 : Client vs32424codyj - There was an error while posting a message to topic xvs/idb/get-signing-identities. There were no receiver listening to that topic.: 11/28/2023 21:09:01Z
```

```
Xamarin.iOS.Windows.WindowsiOSException: Could not install the application 'C:\Users\codyj\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\HotRestart\Signing\QuickDraw.Mobile.app\out\QuickDraw.Mobile.ipa' on the device Cody Business iPhone. Details: ApplicationVerificationFailed|0xE8008015 - Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.sKO8aG/extracted/Payload/QuickDraw.Mobile.app : 0xe8008015 (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)
```

I'm stuck because this issue seems to only occur on this specific project. I've taken the following steps to attempt to resolve it:

- Revoked all certificates in my apple developer portal & had VS automatically create it
- Removed my Apple user from VS and re-added it / revoked API keys and recreated
- Attempted to run on another windows machine and mac
- Cleaned, rebuilt, altered csproj to make it as barebones as possible
- tried manual provisioning

I've also created a fresh Maui project and it deploys to the iOS device fine. In addition to that, I've copied the PropertyGroup that defines the signing key & provisioning profile from the fresh maui project (that worked) into the problematic project. In theory, I'd expect this to solve it because it's using a wildcard identifier.

Everything I do results in this error just for this project. I'm not sure what files would be nescessary to help diagnose the issue so I will provide the full log as well as the csproj.

[csproj](https://pastebin.com/RQJ4Ymjr)

[full log](https://pastebin.com/qmvyrz69)

Comment: Does your project contain the Entitlements.plist file？If so, can you indicate which entries are included in the file?